# Regular Expression pattern : alphanumeric(compulsory) , some special characters (optional)

Tags: regex, html, html-input

I have this:

```
<input type="password" value="" pattern="^(?=.{8,}$)(([a-zA-Z0-9])\2?(?!\2))+$" required/>
```

The non consecutive repeating characters work fine but I am having trouble making it strictly alphanumeric and allow some special characters( ! $ ( ) , - . : ; ? @ { } [ ] ^_ "). The special characters are not compulsory but okay if inputted by user.

summary:

1.Must be between 8 and 30 characters
   2.Must not contain 3 consecutive repeating characters
   3.Must have a minimum of 1 letter
   4.Must have a minimum of 1 number
   5.Only the following special characters are allowed: ! $ ( ) , - . : ; ? @ { } [ ] ^_ ~ `"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am having trouble making it strictly alphanumeric and allow some special characters

You can use this regex:

```
^(?=\D*\d)(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=[\w!$(),.:;?@{}\[\]^-]{8,}$)((.)\2?(?!\2))+$
```

Comment: it still does not allow the special chars and not enforcing alphanumeric. :(

Comment: Thanks for your response. Using your regex, it now allows the special characters but still not making alphanumeric required.